# jQuery/browser issue with hover events on select

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, position, jquery-hover

first of all I looked for my problem and found only not closely related topics and I believe this could be something different than the ones I found on google and thanks for your time to look into my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/dSJMG/

Here you can see a demo where I use jQuery 1.8 and have a div which contains label and select elements, these have been switched on hover event to provide edit functionality, and found that when hovering the field and selecting any option in the select dropdown, sometimes the mouseleave event is triggered however I didn't leave the option list with my mouse pointer.
This seems to be happening non deterministic way, more often when moving the pointer on the options a bit faster (but still not leaving its area).
Also I could reproduce it on every major browser, however I know only IE has this bug officially.

This could be positioning related, because when I increased the space between the container and its children the issue seemed to be fixed.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var $select = $("select.sel"), $label = $("label.lab");

$(".cont").hover(function(evt) {
    if (evt.type === "mouseenter") {
        $select.val($label.hide().text()).show();
        $select.addClass('active');
    } else {
        if(!$select.hasClass('active')) {
            $label.text($select.hide().val()).show();
            $select.removeClass('active');
        }
    }
});

$("select.sel").change(function() {
    if($select.hasClass('active')) {
        $label.text($select.hide().val()).show();
        $select.removeClass('active');             
    }
});
```

Change jQuery [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dSJMG/14/)

Comment: Thanks for the code update, I hoped this is a known bug and doesn't need to use any workaround.